# Count unique value of a range

Tags: excel, count, excel-2010, unique, countif

I know there is a way to count unique values using sum(if(frequency())), but my problem doesn't solve with that. Here is a screenshot I'm providing an image link for you to understand it, see if anyone can help me.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/quk5vm744glx5x7/countif%20frequency.jpg

Here I want to put a formula to count the unique number of cheques for the names please feel free to ask any other question, and please see if anyone can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a pivot table to summarize the table.  You will then have the results that you want, automatically updated if you have new people in the future.

You would easily be able to filter and slice it based on period or user or amount.

**EDIT**
I just noticed the duplicate cheque numbers.

Create a "helper" column that identifies if the cheque number is unique.  In E2 put:

```
=IF(MATCH(D2,D:D,0)=ROW(D2),1,0)
```

You could then either use the pivot table, or in J2 use the following formula:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,RIGHT(F2,LEN(F2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(F2," ","|",
 LEN(F2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F2," ",""))))),E:E)
```

Comment: your formula worked like a charm.. thank you very much for helping :)